# Cors nginx and setCookie with JWT token

Tags: php, authentication, nginx, cookies

I have project divided into frontend and backend. Backend is available on mydomain.com/api and I need to develop frontend project which cooperate with backend on mydomaion.com/api.

First problem was CORS - It`s ok. I allowed CORS.
But now I am facing to second problem. When I sign-in in frontend, backend set BEARER token.

```
setcookie('BEARER', $token, 0, '/', '', false, true);
```

I expect when I send next request to API, cookie BEARER header automatically attached. Unfortunatelly no headers attached and therefore I get response 401 Unauthorized because I am not logged in.

I think that problem is domain. Frontend running on my local PC mydomain.test and API running on mydomain.com.

I think I need something like this:

```
setcookie('BEARER', $token, 0, '/', '*', false, true);
```

But this is not working too.

Solve somebody same problem?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what are you using in your backend, but i think your problem is on your CORS config. Normally you need to allow the origin you are using, headers and credentials. In ASP.NET CORE it would look something like this:

```
 builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8080")
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
                    .AllowCredentials();
```

And since you are using jwt token you need to add it:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            //your jwt options config
        })
)
```